# Código VBA: Bloquear células especificadas sem proteger toda a planilha

Tags: excel-vba

Boa tarde

Conseguem ajudar-me com a fórmula abaixo?

Preciso incluir mais colunas e outras células especificas.. mas não quero bloquear tudo.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 1 Then
    If Target.Row = 3 Or Target.Row = 5 Then
        Beep
        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Offset(0, 1).Select
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue o codigo com melhorias:

As regras são simples, no codigo onde esta: **vStrLocaisProibidos = "A3,A5"** voce deve declarar todos os locais onde voce deseja não ter permissão. Intercalado por virgula (,)
Exemplo.

Quero bloquear a Colunas A, C, D, E, G em diante até Z e tambem quero bloquar linhas 3 e 5 e a celula B2. Dessa forma voce tem muita flexibilidade para fazer qualquer combinação.

> vStrLocaisProibidos = "A:A,C:D,E:E,G:Z,3:3,5:5,B2"

sugestão. para nao ter que digitar tu isso a baixo. Selecione todas as areas que vc quer bloquear com o mouse e o CTRL pressionado. E depois no imediate vc usa

> ?selection.address

para pegar os endereços sem sofrimento. :D

```
Dim vErrLineMove As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim vStrLocaisProibidos As String
Dim vRngReturn As Variant
Dim vMaxError As Long

    'definido para parar depois que a macro tenta colocar um novo local
    'depois de 10 tentativas. Ele para e mantem o cursor a onde for.
    vMaxError = 10
    vStrLocaisProibidos = "A:A,C:D,E:E,G:Z,3:3,5:5,B2"

    If vStrLocaisProibidos = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    Set vRngReturn = Application.Intersect(Target.Worksheet.Range(vStrLocaisProibidos), Target)

    If Not vRngReturn Is Nothing Then
        Beep
        If vErrLineMove < vMaxError Then
            vErrLineMove = vErrLineMove + 1
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Offset(0, 1).Select
        End If
    End If

    vErrLineMove = 0

End Sub
```

att.

Hudson Komuro

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!!!